# kotlin interfaces, sealed classes and generic types usage (using child classes of generic types in interface functions)

Tags: kotlin, generics, syntax

I have this sealed class

```
sealed class S3FileUploaderRequest {
    abstract val s3Configuration: S3Configuration

    data class S3UploadRequest(
            val uploadData: S3UploadData,
            override val s3Configuration: S3Configuration
    ) : S3FileUploaderRequest()

    data class S3DeleteRequest(
            val path: String,
            override val s3Configuration: S3Configuration
    ) : S3FileUploaderRequest()

    data class S3MultiUploadRequest(
            val multiUploadData: List<S3UploadData>,
            override val s3Configuration: S3Configuration
    ) : S3FileUploaderRequest()

    data class S3MultiDeleteRequest(
            val paths: List<String>,
            override val s3Configuration: S3Configuration
    ) : S3FileUploaderRequest()
}
```

And this interface:

```
interface FileUploader<T, S> {
    suspend fun multiUploadFile(request: T): S
    suspend fun multiDeleteFile(request: T): List<S>
    suspend fun uploadFile(request: T): S
    suspend fun deleteFile(request: T): S
}
```

I would like to use the child classes of data class S3FileUploaderRequest es entry parameter of interface functions, somethig like this:

```
interface FileUploader<T, S> {
        suspend fun multiUploadFile(request: out T): out S
        suspend fun multiDeleteFile(request: out T): List<S>
        suspend fun uploadFile(request: out T): out S
        suspend fun deleteFile(request: out T): out S
    }
```

Is possible to do this? I feel like kotlin should be able to do this but don't find the proper syntax for it.

Update:

I would like to implement the interface this way:

```
    @Singleton
class S3FileUploader() : FileUploader<S3FileUploaderRequest, S3FileUploaderResponse> {

    override suspend fun uploadFile(request: S3UploadRequest): S3UploadResponse {
        //DO STUFF
    }

    override suspend fun deleteFile(request: S3DeleteRequest): S3DeleteResponse {
        //DO STUFF
    }

    override suspend fun multiUploadFile(request: S3MultiUploadRequest): S3MultiUploadResponse {
        //DO STUFF
    }

    override suspend fun multiDeleteFile(request: S3MultiDeleteRequest): List<S3DeleteResponse> {
        //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried to implement the interface `FileUploader` with this: `FileUpoader<S3FileUploaderRequest, Response>` and overriding function `multiUploadFile(S3UploadRequest)` but this can't be done because I don't know the way to tell `FileUploader` interface that his functions should take child classes of `T` (`S3FileUploaderRequest`) as input parameter

Comment: Might you be looking for `<T : S3FileUploaderRequest>`?